# ActionController::RoutingError stimulus-loading.js importmap-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, stimulusjs

I'm using Rails 6.1 with @hotwired/stimulus and importmap.

I'm getting this error in dev env.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/stimulus-loading.js")
```

importmap.rb:

```
pin "application"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.js"
```

The temporary solution is to set the stimulus-loading precompiled file:

```
pin "application"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.js"    
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "/assets/stimulus-loading-1fc59770fb1654500044afd3f5f6d7d00800e5be36746d55b94a2963a7a228aa.js"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.js"
```

The only 'pin' which is failing is stimulus-loading.js. why?
I already followed https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails
Any help, idea or comment is very welcome. Thanks for your time!

Gems:

```
'ruby' '2.6.8'
'rails', '~> 6.1'
'importmap-rails'
'stimulus-rails'
'turbo-rails'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this solved the problem for me. Try adding to config/environnement/development.rb the following clause:

```
 config.assets.debug = true
```

Comment: This didn't solve my issue, but thanks for the idea.